# What's the difference between Ctrl-Z and kill -STOP?

Tags: bash, shell-script, signals

When I run a command (`make` on a large project) from the shell, I can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to stop the process and return to the shell. Subsequently, I can run `fg` to continue the process.

I'm trying to write a shell script to automate this (specifically, to check my CPU temperature every few seconds and stop the process if it gets too hot, since my computer is prone to overheating). My first attempt worked like this (simplified):

```
make &
subpid="$!"

sleep 2
# If the CPU temperature is too high...
kill -STOP "$subpid"

sleep 2
# If the CPU temperature has dropped to safe levels...
kill -CONT "$subpid"

wait "$subpid"
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work; sending `SIGSTOP` to the process didn't pause it (as made evident by its continuing to send output to the terminal). I ran `make &` at the command line, sent `SIGSTOP`, and checked the process status with `ps`; it was listed as stopped (and started again when I sent `SIGCONT`), but it was still spewing output and driving up my core temperature! Stopping it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> never had this problem, but I don't know how to do that in a script.

What makes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> different from `kill -STOP`, and how can I get the behavior of the former in a shell script?

Comment: And yes, `make` is being run recursively. In fact, I think it goes several levels deep.

Answer (score 13):

> What makes Ctrl-Z different from `kill -STOP`, and how can I get the behavior of the former in a shell script?

`CTRL-Z` usually sends SIGTSTP (which can be blocked), and - apart from other things - shells often reset tty to a previously saved state on these occasions. More importantly however, the controlling terminal process group is set to the shell's PID (and then again to a PID of a job resumed with `fg`).

Back to your original problem: using a temperature dependent frequency scaling like e.g. [Cpufreqd](http://www.linux.it/~malattia/wiki/index.php/Cpufreqd) might be actually a better hammer for your nail.

Comment: With _which can be **blocked**_ do you mean _ignored_ or _handled_?

Comment: Of those two I would probably settle for *handled*, for ignoring something is a particular way of handling it.

Answer (score 5):

You can send a signal to all processes in a process group if you specify negative PID value - PGID of a session leader.

```
kill -STOP -"$subpid"
```

Note: To run a program in a new session use `setsid make`. But in your case I think it is not needed. However, if make is run recursively, each instance of make could be its own leader (I'm not sure about that).

Another option could be to use `killall`:

```
killall -STOP make
```

The difference between Ctrl+Z and kill -STOP:

- Ctrl-Z actually sends TSTP, which can be blocked.
- STOP cannot be blocked.

Comment: The PGID approach didn't work, and produced the following line of output: `/usr/local/bin/myscript: line 38: kill: (-10202) - No such process`. The background processes continued to run. I don't think the `killall` approach would work because some of the subprocesses appear to be `sh` rather than `make`.

Comment: It seems that the process you are sending the signal to has already finished. Subprocesses named sh are spawned by make. In your case of make and many subprocesses the best would probably be to obtain PIDs of all the children and STOP them all.

Comment: It ended up working when I did it manually from the shell, but not in a shell script. I'm thinking this is because when I did it manually, the root PID (which the others inherited their PGID from) was that of the first `make` command, but when I did it from the script, the root PID was from the shell script itself.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to stop the `make` process; you want to stop the `make` process *and* all of its child processes.  I bet make was being run recursively.

You could try `set -m`, then use `%1` instead of `"$subpid"`.

The `set -m` enables "job control", which is off by default inside scripts.  I think it should work for your use case, although [people seem to think it's a bad idea in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690266/why-cant-i-use-job-control-in-a-bash-script).

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is used to kill a process with signal `SIGINT`, by other words it is a polite **kill**.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>  is used to suspend a process by sending it the signal **SIGSTP**, which is like a sleep signal, that can be undone and the process can be resumed again.

However when a process is suspended, we can resume it again by `fg` *(resume in foreground)* and `bg` *(resume in background)*, but I can't resume a killed process, that is a difference between using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

How to **view** suspended process ?

When you have multiple suspended commands, to have them listed, you use the `jobs` command, and output will be :

```
[1]-  Stopped                 cat
[2]+  Stopped                 vi
```

How to **kill** a suspended process in background?

By using `kill` command :

`kill %n` where **n** is the job number (the one in square brackets from the jobs output), so I want to kill cat : `kill %1`.